# Django and alwaysdata: internationalization not applied

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I developed a Django application that I deployed in tests on alwaysdata

The application is easily accessible but internationalization does not apply

However, I did 'execute' the internationalization during the deployment in my virtual environnement (/home/mereva/intensetbm-etool) (django-admin makemessages -l fr and django-admin compilesmessages) and I don't have an error message (normal command return)

Locally, I have no problem, my site is well translated into French when the web browser is in French ...

Deployment on alwaysdata is not trivial ...

**architecture of my project:**

/home/mereva/envTbm (virtual environment)

/home/mereva/intensetbm-etool (project folder containing manage.py)

/home/mereva/intensetbm_static (static file)

/home/mereva/intensetbm-etool/intenseTBM_eTool/settings.py (root of the project containing settings.py)

/home/mereva/intensetbm-etool/locale (Django translation file)

**settings.py**

```
import os
import psycopg2.extensions
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rqps9azjw7i0@_(qxirwr!@0w3f)$prsky9l7bt8t-(y)_tiuj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','localhost', '[::1]']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mereva.alwaysdata.net']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrap4',

    'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig',
    'monitor.apps.MonitorConfig',
    'randomization.apps.RandomizationConfig',
    'parameters.apps.ParametersConfig',
    'unblind.apps.UnblindConfig',
    'pharmacy.apps.PharmacyConfig',
    'export.apps.ExportConfig',

    'django_extensions',
    # 'debug_toolbar',

    'partial_date',
    'safedelete',
    'simple_history',

]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'randomization.middleware.stock',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    # 'randomization.middleware.AutoLogout',
]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

ROOT_URLCONF = 'intenseTBM_eTool.urls'

TEMPLATES = [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'registration/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'monitor/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'unblind/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pharmacy/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'export/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),    
        ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'randomization.context_processors.data_context_processor',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'intenseTBM_eTool.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'mereva_intensetbm',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD':'*********',
        'HOST':'postgresql-mereva.alwaysdata.net',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        'NAME': 'registration.validators.MerevaValidator',
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Lists of languages site supports.
# LANGUAGES = (
#     ('en', _('English')),
#     ('fr', _('French')),
# )

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'unblind/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pharmacy/static'),
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mereva/intensetbm_static'

# INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']

LOGIN_URL = 'home'
# my_project/settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'randomization.email.CustomEmailBackend'

# paramétrage du seuil de disponibilité des médiaments ASPIRIN/PLACEBO pour la randomisation
# is_randomizable (randomization.models et randomization_extras.py)
DRUG_DISPONIBILITY = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

# SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 900  # 900 - >15 minutes = 15 * 60
# SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True
# SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY_GRACE_PERIOD = 60 # group by minute
# paramètres utilisés pour middleware personalisé AutoLogout en cours d'écriture
TIME = 15*60  # 15 minutes : 15*60 or your time in seconds
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = TIME    # change expired session
SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = TIME  # logout

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean with internationalization doesn't apply?

I see you missed some settings and some middleware, namely [LANGUAGES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#languages) and  [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGE_CODE)

```
MIDDLEWARE = [ 
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...]

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('en-US', _('English')),
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
LOCALE_PATHS = [...]
```

Next, in the code, you should use **ugettext_lazy** instead of **ugettext** and check the locale file and remove all **fuzzy**ies from it, then compile it again.

I can give more suggestions if you'd share a concrete code snippet that doesn't get translated.

Comment: you are right I forgot theses settings but unfortunatly, even with only few words are translated...

Comment: @SLATER Did you check django.po file, all words that are intended for translations are there? Did you remove all fuzzy occurrences from django.po file? Looks I've replied to your first issue, that i18n doesn't apply. Now it applies, but not all words are getting translated, yes?

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed the .po files and as my application is translated in local, I think it is a settings problem... only VERY few words are translated...

Comment: I saw now LOCALE_PATHS is not defined, can you define it and try again?

Comment: @SLATER You welcome. I've edited the reply above, so you can mark my answer useful. Thanks.